# Databricks Delta Live Tables: Difference between STREAMING and INCREMENTAL

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

Is there a difference between `CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE` and `CREATE INCREMENTAL LIVE TABLE`? The documentation is mixed: For instance, `STREAMING` is used [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-sql-ref.html#sql-api-specification), while `INCREMENTAL` is used [here](https://databricks.com/discover/pages/getting-started-with-delta-live-tables). I have tested both and so far I have not noticed any difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

1. Conceptual - incremental means that the minimal data changes are applied to a destination table, we don't recompute full data set when new data arrive. This is how is explained in the [Getting Started book](https://databricks.com/discover/pages/getting-started-with-delta-live-tables#bronze-datasets).
2. Syntax - `CREATE INCREMENTAL LIVE TABLE` was the original syntax for pipelines that were processing streaming data.  But it was deprecated in the favor of `CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE`, but the old syntax is still supported for compatibility reasons.

Comment: In summary you are saying they are the same thing but one is deprecated syntax.